# Работа с клавиатурой в определенном окне

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, клавиатура

Как сделать, чтобы код из функции test выполнялся в определенном окне, например 'chrome.exe'?

```
import keyboard


def test(none):
 pass

keyboard.on_press_key('k', test)
keybaord.wait()
```